# Can't get Bootstrap nav-tabs/tab-pane to work correctly when creating them dynamically with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a website on a third-party eCommerce platform and I would like to make an easy way for users to create a tab section through the platforms description textarea.

My idea so far is to have them create various divs with an attribute of data-tab-name="{Description,Reviews,etc}" and whatever content inside of the div. The jQuery code I've written selects all of the data-tab-names and turns them into Bootstrap tabs when the code is executed. I've written the code so that it appears exactly as it does when I code it out manually, but for some reason the tabs are not functioning for me.

Within the code snippet the tabs do not work at all and on the actual page the tabs works but all of them get set to active for some reason and I can only click each section one time before the tabs become unclickable. https://partyz.ourers.com/items/dunk_tank/

Anyone mind reviewing my codepen and letting me know if I'm doing something wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    function cssEncode(name) {
      return name.replace(/ /g, "-").toLowerCase();
    }

    var dataAttr = "data-tab-name";
    var tabDivs = $("div[" + dataAttr + "]");
    var navTabs = $('<div class="nav nav-tabs">');
    var tabContent = $('<div class="tab-content" id="tabs"></div>');
    var tabs = [];
    var tabPanes = [];
    tabDivs.each(function(e) {
      var name = $(this).attr(dataAttr);
      var encodedName = cssEncode(name);
      tabs.push(
        '<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#' +
        encodedName +
        '">' +
        name +
        "</a></li>"
      );
      var tabPane = $(
        '<div class="tab-pane fade" id="' + encodedName + '"></div>'
      ).append($(this).html());
      tabPanes.push(tabPane);
      $(this).detach();
    });
    navTabs.append(tabs.join(""));
    navTabs.find("li:first").addClass("active");
    tabContent.append(tabPanes);
    tabContent.find("div.tab-pane:first").addClass("active in");
    var tabsContainer = $('<div class="tabs"></div>');
    tabsContainer.append(navTabs);
    tabsContainer.append(tabContent);
    $(".iseo-item-page .col-md-12").append(tabsContainer);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row iseo-item-page">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div data-tab-name="Description">

        <!-- Start Description Tab Content -->
        <p>
          <span style="color: rgb(102, 102, 102); font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">Party Zone Inflatables knows how to get the party started with dunk tank rentals in New Orleans, La! This is a top pick for fundraisers and once you see this awesome rental in action, you will understand why! Dunk tanks are loads of fun and everyone will be laughing; from the dunkers to the dunkees, to the spectators! Dunk tanks are fun for all kinds of events and make great fund raising opportunities for church groups, schools, and other organizations. Our New Orleans customers love our Dunk Tank rentals and you will too.</span></p>
        <p style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0px 0px 1em; border: 0px; outline: 0px; background-image: initial; background-position: 0px 0px; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: baseline; text-size-adjust: 100%; color: rgb(102, 102, 102); font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif;">
          Also, check out our <a href="/category/yard_games/">yard</a><a href="/category/interactive_games/" style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; background: 0px 0px; vertical-align: baseline; text-size-adjust: 100%; color: rgb(46, 163, 242); text-decoration-line: none;">&nbsp;games</a>&nbsp;for
          other ideas on event rentals. Book online now or call us today!</p>
        <p style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; background-image: initial; background-position: 0px 0px; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: baseline; text-size-adjust: 100%; color: rgb(102, 102, 102); font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif;">
          Thank you for choosing Party Zone Inflatables for your Dunk Tank rentals in New Orleans, LA. We are proud to be a locally owned and operated company that has been serving the River Parish areas since 2009. Our company&rsquo;s main goal is driven on providing
          professional customer service each and every rental as well as offering a selection which is geared to fit any party planners budget. We want to go above and beyond our customer&rsquo;s expectation and provide outstanding customer service 100%
          of the time.&nbsp;<a href="/contact_us/" style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; background: 0px 0px; vertical-align: baseline; text-size-adjust: 100%; color: rgb(46, 163, 242); text-decoration-line: none;">Click Here</a>&nbsp;to
          contact us today!</p>
        <!-- End Description Tab Content -->

      </div>
      <!-- End Decription Tab -->
      <!-- Video Tab -->
      <div data-tab-name="Video">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="video-responsive">

              <!-- Start Video Tab Content -->
              <iframe allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7HlyQiOMAJY" width="560"></iframe></div>
            <!-- End Video Tab Content -->

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Video Tab -->
      <!-- Review Tab -->
      <div data-tab-name="Reviews">

        <!-- Start Review Tab Content -->
        <div id="wpac-review">
          &nbsp;</div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          wpac_init = window.wpac_init || [];
          wpac_init.push({
            widget: 'Review',
            id: 12692
          });
          (function() {
            if ('WIDGETPACK_LOADED' in window) return;
            WIDGETPACK_LOADED = true;
            var mc = document.createElement('script');
            mc.type = 'text/javascript';
            mc.async = true;
            mc.src = 'https://embed.widgetpack.com/widget.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(mc, s.nextSibling);
          })();
        </script>
        <!-- End Review Tab Content -->

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

(It's showing me script error in StackOverflow's code editor, but I ran it through jshint.com and it doesn't say anything about a script error and codepen isn't showing an error either. I also skimmed through the code and do not see anyt typos, etc.)

Comment: It looks like you are not using `removeClass('active')` on tabs before adding it to the clicked tab.

Comment: Thanks for replying @JonathanBowman . If I'm adding this to document.ready() it should only get executed once though, right? I edited the code so that it uses the tab("show") function from bootstrap.js instead of setting the class to active directly and I'm still having the same issue. Here is an updated codepen: https://codepen.io/CodeBradley/pen/VBzJXz (not sure how to use the SO one in a comment)